# A universe where humans are the only violent species in the universe?

Tags: story-identification

Does anybody know about any form of fiction (literature, TV, movie, video games, anything really) where humans are the only aggressive/violent sentient life form? I'm not talking about Alan Dean Foster's The Damned Trilogy or something similar, where the aliens are engaging in violence but are bad at it, or where the pacifist "good" aliens are forced to fight the violent "bad" aliens against their will.

Comment: I'm sorry, but recommendation questions are off-topic. If you're loking abot one particular story, consult [this page](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see the requirements and guidelines for story identification questions.

Comment: Can I reword this to fit somehow? Can you suggest what other tag to post it with? I'm not looking for a suggestion. I'm literally looking to see if this idea exists in fiction anywhere. I've been posting in a lot of places and coming up short.

Comment: A known hack is to ask for "the first story to feature X", which is effectively the same, but technically not a list or recommendation question. You could try that :)

Answer (score 3):

There's the short story "All the Way Back" by [Michael Shaara](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Shaara). Spoilers follow.

> Humanity spreads out into the galaxy and discovers only sterile, destroyed worlds. Eventually contact is made with the peaceful Galactic Federation, and it is revealed that a violent race threatened the galaxy, and their worlds were destroyed in a great conflict. Except, apparently, that one was missed, called the Earth.